# How to sort a TStringList according to it's values in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I create a `TStringList` that contains name/value pair and I want to sort `TStringList` according to it's values and then Names with max value are assigned to Labels.

```
SL: TStringList;
SL:= TStringList.Create; 


SL.Values['chelsea']:= '5';
SL.Values['Liverpool']:= '15';
SL.Values['Mancity']:= '10';
SL.Values['Tot']:= '0';
SL.Values['Manunited']:= '20';
```

Finally this `TStringList` must be sorted in According to values. actually first name must be a name with highest value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the `CustomSort` method. Like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

function StringListSortProc(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  i1, i2: Integer;
begin
  i1 := StrToInt(List.ValueFromIndex[Index1]);
  i2 := StrToInt(List.ValueFromIndex[Index2]);
  Result := i2 - i1;
end;

var
  SL: TStringList;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Values['Chelsea'] := '5';
    SL.Values['Liverpool'] := '15';
    SL.Values['Man City'] := '10';
    SL.Values['Spurs'] := '0';
    SL.Values['Man United'] := '20';

    WriteLn('Before sort');
    for Index := 0 to SL.Count-1 do
      WriteLn('  ' + SL[Index]);
    SL.CustomSort(StringListSortProc);

    WriteLn;
    WriteLn('After sort');
    for Index := 0 to SL.Count-1 do
      WriteLn('  ' + SL[Index]);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

I can't remember when the `ValueFromIndex` method was added. If it is not present in Delphi 7 then you can emulate it like this:

```
function ValueFromIndex(List: TStringList; Index: Integer): string;
var
  Item: string;
begin
  Item := List[Index];
  Result := Copy(Item, Pos('=', Item) + 1, MaxInt);
end;

function StringListSortProc(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  i1, i2: Integer;
begin
  i1 := StrToInt(ValueFromIndex(List, Index1));
  i2 := StrToInt(ValueFromIndex(List, Index2));
  Result := i2 - i1;
end;
```

Program output:

```
Before sort
  Chelsea=5
  Liverpool=15
  Man City=10
  Spurs=0
  Man United=20

After sort
  Man United=20
  Liverpool=15
  Man City=10
  Chelsea=5
  Spurs=0
```

Comment: "*I can't remember when the ValueFromIndex method was added*" - it was added in Delphi 7.